# Retry Mechanism

Tags: design-patterns, rate-limiting, retry-logic, exponential-backoff

I am seeking guidance for an issue related to an image downloading system. Our system interacts with various external suppliers via Kafka messages, and each message contains a list of image URLs from different domains to be downloaded.

The challenge is that we have to respect the rate limits of these domains. If we make too many requests, we receive a 429 "Too Many Requests" response. We tried to mitigate this by implementing an exponential backoff strategy, but some domains still rate-limit us even after a minute of downtime.

Additionally, we must maintain sequential processing for each supplier's messages to avoid database conflicts, meaning that the messages from a supplier must be processed in their original order of arrival.

We're left wondering how to navigate these rate limits effectively, while ensuring sequential request handling.

I am thinking of solutions like Circuit Breaker pattern. Kindly suggest some ideas.

Comment: Whenever you are receiving a 429 response then is the [`Retry-After`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) header populated there?

Comment: @PeterCsala thanks for taking the time out to help me. No, most of the external suppliers who we call are not sending us this header in the response.

Comment: Do you have any information about the rate limiting? I mean something like: X requests / hour are allowed and/or Y requests / day.

Comment: For some suppliers we do have rate limit information but majority of the suppliers are without such info.
For those who has shared the info, it is close to 10K requests per hour. But, the problem is that there is a single kafka topic where all messages from the suppliers are written into and our service consumes from this topic. But for a given supplier, if after when our service makes a request, if we get a failure response code of like 5xx or 4xx, then we retry 3 times with exponential delay starting from 10 secs.